# Older flags showing as active

Tags: support, flags

I have a few older flags, the oldest one being from Jun 27 at 23:03, still showing as active.

Since then I've had over 20 newer flags handled. Is there an issue with the displaying of the status, or perhaps an issue with the queue (I don't know how the flag queue works)?

Comment: My answer to the question I've marked as duplicate explains the exact issue you are seeing. :)

Comment: Crap, so did the answer I was about to submit :-(

Comment: @AndrewBarber We're not talking about a few hours or days anymore, but more than a month, so I assumed something was wrong. "not in an absolute, set order" could explain it I guess :)

Comment: We've actually had a considerably high volume of flags lately. I've only been a mod since March, so I don't know any longer history, but the last month or so we've had more flags hanging around then I've seen since getting my diamond. That said; since you mention it, I'm going to go check out some of your active flags now ;)

Comment: Incidentally, the oldest flag I see from you (From June) is a 'close' flag; ♦ mods no longer get those; they go to the Close review queue.

Comment: I've added information to my answer at the dupe concerning the new way close flags are handled.