# Why are many of my flags still waiting for review?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, flags, flag-history

I have included an image of my flagging history below:

[image]

Of the 51 flags still waiting for review, 40 have been in this waiting state for more than a month. What could cause this?

Comment: Where do you get the number 40? It says 51 there.

Comment: @codygray, 11 are recent. Others are older.

Comment: I would have said you were flag-hellbanned, but you have too many helpful flags for that to be likely. And it would not explain recent flags, as the behaviour was changed recently.

Comment: @MadScientist : Why it is 51 ? and When it will come down ?

Comment: Can't you see *which* flags are still waiting, and link to an example? Like maybe the posts you flagged have meanwhile been deleted?

Comment: 409 helpful/ 19 declined is a very good ratio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does it take so long to review a flag suggested by a user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174259/why-does-it-take-so-long-to-review-a-flag-suggested-by-a-user) and [Older flags showing as active](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191624/older-flags-showing-as-active)

Comment: I don't know where you got the impression that 40 of your flags have been pending for more than a month. Almost all of them were raised in the last *week*.

Comment: Was that a close flag? [*"Moderators no longer see the "Close" flags in our queue; they will go to the Close review queue; so they remain open for a long time."*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174259/why-does-it-take-so-long-to-review-a-flag-suggested-by-a-user/174268#174268) (Though that might be [a recent change](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/174268/5)?)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn : Sir, **[This is one example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541713/is-it-possible-to-format-the-java-script-code-embedded-in-a-cshtml-file)**

Comment: @PKKG: OK, but that's your *only* flag that's more than a month old, and it's a close flag so as Arjan stated moderators don't see it. It probably got lost and forgotten.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Two reasons, the first is just a backlog. There are almost 700 flags soaking in the moderator queue right now, so I suspect you'll see many of them acted upon in the next day or so. While the mods do check the queue and handle serious issues over the weekend, it's not unusual for less urgent flags to be processed during the week since folks have other stuff to do.

The second reason is some of your flags are of the RecommendClosure type, which recently changed so that they go through the review system instead of right to the moderator queue, in an effort to alleviate some of the backlog I just described. The community can handle close flags on their own unless a question has gone into a close / reopen cycle a few times.

When this change happened, some of the flags of this type that were already in the moderator queue went into a sort of limbo, something we're looking at now. Don't worry about them too much, as they'll be dropping off shortly.

Comment: Is that a general statement or specific to @PKKG? I also have quite a few month-old flags pending.

Comment: @AndersUP General - I'll take a look at your flags as well. There aren't _too_ many folks with flags still in limbo, going to try and see if I can figure out just how many

Comment: Is it possible some of my flags are in limbo too, instead of just being part of a long queue? See my duplicate link in the comment.

Comment: @Stijn If anything is lingering flagged _before_ July 1 or 2, it _might_ be in limbo. I'm going to see if I can grab a dev to check and possibly flush these out for everyone

Comment: In fact, every single one of PKKG's 41 currently outstanding flags are close vote flags, so I think that explains almost all of this. Even with the moderator flag queue as large as it is this morning, the average moderator flag handling time over the last month is about 6 hours. The same is true for @AndersUP.