# I've got an old flag active

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-history

I have a flag from 12 July 2013 which is Active. Having arrived at the stage of looking around at the stuff in my Profile a little more, I noticed this yesterday. OK, I thought, no big harm, people are working on a number of "to Close" things, so let it take its (further) time before mentioning if finally necessary.

Of course, this morning I find a new answer and a new comment from the Answerer.

The level of opinion is stupendous, requiring reading history backwards. Look at the Answerer's negative-voted Answers to form an opinion of whether they'd be open to "engagement" even. Solid opinion.

Of course, TS/OP has done a runner long ago.

When reviewing the question, bear in mind that JOBLIB and STEPLIB will have appeared at some point in the development of the IBM Mainframe operating system OS/360 (which started in the early '60s at the latest). Not necessarily at the same time. Not necessarily at an early point. Probably whilst punched-cards still predominated. Etc...

So, if at all possible, can there be some votes to put it on Hold, or however that works, please?

Here's the Q: [Why the StEPLIB always overrides the JOBLIB,in JCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507929/why-the-steplib-always-overrides-the-joblib-in-jcl)

Forgot the image: Replaced by House-Style Image below.

Does it *need* the red circle?

[image: Super-improved image]

Comment: Is there ever a situation where red free-hand circles are not needed? :) I wonder if this is essentially the same issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194803/old-flags-appear-as-active

Comment: @Bart Yes. My opinion. I had checked that link, but although the month is correct, the year makes it irrelevant. I'll change my earilier opinion to No.

Comment: A dammit. I read that as July 2012. So yeah, most likely not the same issue. I blame the lack of a red circle though.

Comment: Blame accepted and correction implemented.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does it take so long to review a flag suggested by a user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174259/why-does-it-take-so-long-to-review-a-flag-suggested-by-a-user) and [Older flags showing as active (duplicate)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191624/older-flags-showing-as-active) Basically, your off-topic flag goes into the close queue, which as you may have noticed keeps on growing.

Comment: Now, why didn't I get a notification of the comment from Stijn? OK, a type of Catch-22. Can't get on the Close queue because the request is on the Close queue and the Close queue is long, and would be made longer by another Close... Oh. This one's going to Close... I bet this disappears a lot more quickly :-)

Comment: Can it at least be closed with one of @Stijn's links, rather than the particular one mentioned, which is far from "an exact duplicate"?

Comment: I've voted to reopen as I now realize it is not the same issue.  I think there is another better duplicate though as I've seen this question several times since June

Comment: @BillWoodger Stijin's first link is not the reason either.  There was a change to how flag to close flags were handled in June, so the March post is not it.

Comment: @psubsee2003 OK, so does Stijn's question also get a vote to re-open, as the March one was given for that? I'm not concerned about this question itself, I was happy just to be patient on discovery. It's just that there is now more, nutty, activity on the original question, so I was sneakily hoping that the Meta Effect may kick in... now I've got two other problems just from all of this (missing notification of Stijn's comment and an odd number of characters reported for the edit when I added 2013 to the question).

Comment: @psubsee2003 The answer in that link was updated in August to reflect those changes.

Comment: @Stijn I read the answer twice to see if I missed something, and he does have a single sentence in there that probably does make it a dup, My initial reaction was based on the fact that I think the active close flags is going to become a bigger issue and deserves more than 1 sentence.

Comment: possible duplicate of: [What's the normal delay for a flag to be dismissed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195185/whats-the-normal-delay-for-a-flag-to-be-dismissed)